# Delete rows from a table if table exists in Redshift otherwise ignore deletion

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift. I want a query to delete selected rows from a redshift table if the table exists otherwise just ignore the statement.

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Your question is not very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Redshift's SQL dialect doesn't contain control-of-flow statements like IF.. THEN so you are not going to be able to do this in a single SQL statement.

Your application or process will need to first query the Redshift table metadata to determine if a table exists e.g.

```
select 1 from pg_tables where schemaname = 'myschema' and tablename = 'myschema';
```

If data is returned (i.e. the table exists) then the application or process will execute the delete statement, if no data is returned the application or process does nothing. Basically you need to handle the "if this then do this" logic externally to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend @Nathan's answer.  I would use python/psycopg2 to set up this logic.  The first query would check for the table's existence in `pg_tables` (eg `SELECT count(1) FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='foo'`), and store the result in a variable.  Then you'd check the results of that variable to decide whether to kick off a second query (your delete).

But, maybe you don't want to do it in Python.  You're just all about Redshift (it's pretty sweet).  You could just run the `DELETE` query in Redshift.  If the table is not present, the query fails and nothing happens.  If the table is, you delete your data.  There's no harm in generating an error here.